# Wanna save value of a text input and then through a button highlight the div with the right id

Tags: jquery, function, search, highlight

I have these divs:

```
<div id="content_area">
    <div id="banner">
        <div id="b1" class="bannerdiv1">b1</div>
        <div id="b2" class="bannerdiv2">b2</div>
    </div>
  <div id="left_col">
        <div id="lc1" class="kolumndiv1">lc1</div>
        <div id="lc2" class="kolumndiv1">lc2</div>
        <div id="lc3" class="kolumndiv1">lc3</div>
        <div id="lc4" class="kolumndiv1">lc4</div>
    </div>
        <div id="right_col">
        <div id="rc1" class="kolumndiv1">rc1</div>
        <div id="rc2" class="kolumndiv1">rc2</div>
        <div id="rc3" class="kolumndiv1">rc3</div>
        <div id="rc4" class="kolumndiv1">rc4</div>
  </div>
```

Here's their css incase you need them:

```
.kolumndiv1 
{border:1px solid #333;height:50px;width:245px;background-color:;#c4f2ef}
.bannerdiv1 
{float:left;border:1px solid #333;height:50px;width:245px;
background-color:#c4f2ef;}
.bannerdiv2 
{float:right;border:1px solid #333;height:50px;width:245px;
background-color:#c4f2ef;}
#b1  {  }
#b2  {  }
#lc1 {  }
#lc2 {  }
#lc3 {  }
#lc4 {  }
#rc1 {  }
#rc2 {  }
#rc3 {  }
#rc4 {  }
```

And this form:

```
<form>
    <input id="search1" name="search1" type="text" value="">
    <button id="search">SÖK</button>
</form>
```

SÖK = search in Swedish

I want to save highlight one of these divs when you search for them and then remove the highlighing when entering the div. What I thought would work was getting the .val(); of the text input and through a switch statement doing so when you .click(); the button addclass(); will be used and then css(); so I can add a new background-color to the div. Then when you mouseenter(); it, I will remove(); the new class.

I removed my old code with all the cases for all the divs, but here's the code for #b1 and #b2

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
var searchfunction = $('input[type=text]').val();
switch (searchfunction) {
    case "b1":
        $('#search').click(function() {
            $('#b1').addClass('banner1');
            $('.banner1').css('background-color', '#CF9');
        });
        $('#b1').mouseenter(function() {
            $('.banner1').remove(); 
        });
    break;
    case "b2":
        $('#search').click(function() {
            $('#b2').addClass('banner2');
            $('.banner1').css('background-color', '#CF9');
        });
        $('#b2').mouseenter(function() {
            $('.banner2').remove(); 
        });
    break;
    default:

    break;      
};  
});
```

I think the problem is that the new class won't overlap the id.

Thx, //Adam

Answer (score 0):

EDIT : My first attempt was full of mistakes, please see this JSFiddle to see what i did : http://jsfiddle.net/BJJ9D/15/

I suggest you to put this on your CSS :

```
.banner1 {background-color:#CF9 !important;}
```

Then you can do it this way in your JS :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search').on('click', function(e) {
        highlight();
    });
});

function highlight() {
    $('#' + $('#search1').val()).addClass('banner1');
    $('#' + $('#search1').val()).mouseenter(function() {
        $('.banner1').removeClass('banner1'); 
    });
}
```

Using a function can let you do something like that easily :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#search').on('click', function(e) {
        highlight();
    });

    $('#search1').on('input', function() {
        highlight();
    });
});

function highlight() {
    $('#' + $('#search1').val()).addClass('banner1');
    $('#' + $('#search1').val()).mouseenter(function() {
        $('.banner1').removeClass('banner1'); 
    });
}
```